# SQL Server 2008 R2 Performance Studio - Data Collection works but View Report throws 'Failed to connect...' 18456 error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I set up SQL Server 2008 R2 Performance Studio data collection from [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2008/06/20/sql-server-2008-performance-studio.aspx). Data collection appears to be working great but, when I right-click on Data Collection --> Reports --> Management Data Warehouse and then select any of the reports to load, I get the following error:

```
'Failed to connect to server sql1.myserver.com. --< Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication.'
```

This is strange because I set up a new SQL login for MDW to use, and I am  logged in to SQL Management Studio with a SQL login as well. A look at the SQL logs gives me this:

```
Date        9/14/2011 11:12:13 PM
Log     Data Collection (Query Statistics)

Log ID      179
Source      Query Statistics
Collection Set Name     Query Statistics
Collection Item Name        
Status      Error
Runtime Execution Mode      Upload
Start Time      9/14/2011 11:12:13 PM
Last Iteration Time     
Finish Time     9/14/2011 11:12:13 PM
Duration (ms)       0
Operator        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Package Execution ID        
Event       
Data Code       

Message
Failed to connecto to the management data warehouse server Inner Error ------------------>
Row#:    0 Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Instance: "IP-0AAAEEDF" Procedure: "" Line#:    1 Error Number:  18456 Error State:   1 Error Severity:  14 Error Message: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." Help File: "(null)", Help context:    0 GUID: {0C733A8B-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}.
OLE DB Error Record dump end.
```

If anyone can provide any help at all, it would help me out immeasurably!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

There may be some datacollection configuration issue. In my case it is working fine. From error message it is obvious there is some authentication issue "sql1.myserver.com. --< Login failed". So Try to configure data collection with different credentials.